# How to label a rectangle with its components

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a rectangle with 2 or more pieces and label those pieces with lines- like so [image]

And here is what I have so far using the basic tikz package and just drawing lines. I am not sure how to add the labels using nodes (I honestly don't really understand the code). Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(8,0)--(8,1)--(0,1)--(0,0);
\draw (5,0)--(5,1);
%\draw[<->, semithick] (0, 0)-- node[lbl] at (4,0){$R$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two rectangles and two lines with arrows and nodes placed `midway`. For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (5,1);
\draw (5,0) rectangle (8,1);
\draw[<->] (0, 1.5) --++ (5,0) node[midway,fill=white] {$R-a$};
\draw[<->] (5, 1.5) --++ (3,0) node[midway,fill=white] {\qty{2}{cm}};
\draw[<->] (0,-0.5) --++ (8,0) node[midway,fill=white] {$R$};
% Auxiliary lines, remove them if you want
\foreach\i in {0,5,8}
  \draw[densely dashed,very thin] (\i, 1.1) --++ (0, 0.5);
\foreach\i in {0,8}
  \draw[densely dashed,very thin] (\i,-0.1) --++ (0,-0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice. Ahhh Juan and the infamous `border=1.618`.

Comment: @anis, classic design, you know :-)

Comment: This is absolutely perfect! Thank you so much!